Resp API working fine locally but giving 403 Invalid Error on Windows Server 2019
I am working on smartgatewayuat hdfcbank API. I created sample request to api in boomerang extension
which is working perfectly fine on local system which has windows 10
I created same sample request to api in boomerang extension on windows server 2019, I am getting error 403 INVALID.
I cross checked api key and other header values, all are ok. I added User Agent header as suggested by somewhere else but it didnt help
This is the api documentation link
https://smartgateway.hdfcbank.com/docs/smartgateway-api-ref-basicauth/docs/apis/order-status-api

